# send http to https on GCP load balancer

Tags: node.js, docker, google-cloud-platform

I have a GCP load balancer with a https frontend service. It works like a charm when I visit https://mywebsite.com, but when I visit http://mywebsite.com (so the http-version), I see this message:

[image]

Problably an easy way to solve, but I can't find how exactly. Does someone know the solution?

**Edit:** what I want to achieve is a redirect from http to https. The backend service are container-optimized VM's with a nodejs docker image.

Comment: Have you checked the GCP [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setting-up-http-https-redirect) for redirect?

Comment: Did you create an HTTP frontend?

Comment: How did you configure your LB?

Comment: Please check this guide https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setting-up-http-https-redirect

Comment: can you should me the config of the load balancer?